# How can you reference a rectangle specifically in an array or list

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, xna-4.0

What I am trying to do is create a map generator that will create a grid of rectangles, and then fill random rectangles with different properties.  (For example in a grid of 2x2, 1,1 would be just a normal 'field' in the game, 1,2 would be a base and have different properties than one (like the ability to construct units), 2,1 would be a water tile (and not be passable by units), and 2,2 would be a mountain (similar properties of the previous).  I've created (what I think) is a grid, but when I attempt to reference the array that I created it doesn't work the way I'd like it to.  My guess is that I am not doing it correctly, but here is some code:

```
namespace MapGenie
    {
        public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
        {
            GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

            GameMap[,] basicMap = new GameMap[10,10]; //I have this done in Initialization normally.
            Rectangle[,] basicGrid = new Rectangle[10,10];
        }
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        int GridSize = 20;

        for(int x = 0;x <10;x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                basicMap[x, y] = new GameMap(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures\\Plains"));
                basicMap[x, y].position.X = x * GridSize;
                basicMap[x, y].position.Y = y * GridSize;
                basicGrid[x, y] = new Rectangle(x, y, x * GridSize, y * GridSize);
            }
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //This is what I use to test reference a specific point on the grid, however whenever the 
        //mouse crosses into any of the 3x3 area starting with 1,1 it closes the program.
        if (mousePoint.Intersects(basicGrid[3, 3]))
            this.Exit();
    }
```

So the question is simply: How can I get the program to recognize just a single rectangle in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is on this line:

```
basicGrid[x, y] = new Rectangle(x, y, x * GridSize, y * GridSize);
```

Look at the constructor for `Rectangle` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.rectangle.aspx)). Note that it asks for the width and height of the rectangle. You are giving it something different.

Comment: That makes sense entirely.  After switching the values (So that it multiplies by GridSize in the location bits), and has just a set GridSize length it works, Also I see that I forgot that it runs from origin, so the initial point will be 0,0 not 1,1.  Thanks oodles.